# VW 2015 TDI (EA288) Oil Sensor(s)

Tags: oil, vw, electronic-control-module, tdi

I recently acquired a 2015 VW Jetta TDI, and while someone was taking a long trip, in cold weather, the oil light came on.  A yellow light, which does not match any indicators in the owner's manual.

My suspicion is that it is an oil level indicator, but the car has not returned from the trip.

The outside air temperature was cold (-10C) and several hundred miles later the indicator went out.

At all times the oil level was at the top of the hash mark on the dip stick.

What sensors are on the EA288 engine for oil?  Pressure, obviously.  Level?  Perhaps temperature?

Comment: If you had an image of the light (or a better description) we could help a lot easier. A yellow light is very non-descript.

Comment: Unfortunately, although I asked for a picture I did not get one, and now the annunciator has disappeared. However the image was an oil can, without the squiggly line underneath that is shown in the VW owners manual. And the color was yellow not red.

Comment: That's a little better description. Considering it's a yellow light and it went out, I'd suggest there's no immediate issues with the car. I doubt cold weather will do much to cause it issues, especially if it's running. Engines are self sustaining in the heat department while running (for some silly reason :o) ... Anyway, I'm not sure what the indicator could mean, but I doubt it's anything serious.

Comment: It came on again.  I spent a full day trying to find out what the indicator meant, and no one, and no document I have has explained it yet.  I will dig a few more hours.

Comment: Get an image. I'm sure someone on here can help you determine what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only yellow oil lamp on new VW is for **Oil level**.
It actually have second oil lamp, but it's half red half yellow ( red oil can and yellow circle) and it's for oil pressure.

It has 2 states:

**Lit continuously:** Top up the engine oil as soon as possible.

**Flashing:** The sensor for checking the oil level may be faulty. Check the oil level and top up if necessary.

Sometimes in very cold i experienced the **Flashing** state it's just sensor getting faulty from cold. Once the oil heats up and sensor heats up everything goes fine.